# Live chat system using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created chat box with jQuery and AJAX but the problem is that this chat box is not live. If you want to get newest record you have to refresh page. My code is quite simple and I would like to know what the best way to make it live.

This is my jQuery script :

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13){
        $('#sendbutton').click();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('.chatwindow').load('load.php');

$('#post').submit(function() {
    var userid = "<?php echo $_SESSION["userid"]; ?>";
    var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>";
    var message = $('#textbox').val();

    $.post('post.php', { message: message, username: username, userid: userid }, function(data){ 
        $('.chatwindow').append('<span class="msg" >' + username + ': </span>' + data + '</span><br>');
        $('#textbox').val("");
        $('.chatwindow').scrollTop($('.chatwindow').prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use AJAX to submit message and add to database.

   `$.post("myscript.php", {userId: 123, message: "My message"});`
2. Every several seconds (i.e. 10 seconds) request newer messages by AJAX and prepend (or append) to discussion div.

   `window.setInterval(function() {
       $.post("myscript.php", {action: "refresh", lastId: 1234}, function(response) {
           $("#discussion").prepend(response.html);
           lastId = response.lastId;
       }, "json");
   }, 10000);`

Comment: i would prefer just load with ajax from load.php  every 500ms but thats what i was asking what is the best way to do so , cuz i do not know if its good to load a script every 500ms

Comment: In my opinion, requesting for new messages every 500ms is not a good idea and it is senseless. It will reflect both client side and server side. Еspecially, in case of heavy traffic. Just use 5 seconds (5000ms) instead.

Comment: yea but 5 sec quite alot

Comment: Then just try lower values... It depends the traffic of your chat, processing time of the script, etc. You can also simulate the "real time update" by prepending the newly submitted message immediately and then replacing it on nearest update.

Answer (score 2):

you have different possibilities to establish a live connection between the browser and your server:

1. Use "normal" polling: Make repeating requests (for example every 5 seconds) to - in your case - a PHP script to get the latest messages from other users. When you got new messages, append them to the message list in the same way, you do it in your code.
2. Use "long polling": You make an ajax request to a php script, but this is not answered immediately. Instead the answer is delayed by using the [PHP Sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function. You run a loop, check your message storage (database, file, ...) for new messages, and if there are none, you go to sleep for 1 second (as an example). If there are new message, you send them to the browser. Consider the maximum php script run time in this case. With this method, you lower the load on the server as you need fewer HTTP calls.
3. Use websockets, which use a realtime connection between the webbrowser and the server. This may be the best method to accomplish what you want to do, but you need to install an additional server software on your webserver. Implementing websockets are not possible with PHP directly, if I am not mistaken. [Here](https://phpbuilder.com/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets/) you find an example how to work with websockets.

If you need to use pure PHP, option 2 would be the best for your needs. From the technology point of view option 3 is the way to do this in these days.
Option 1 is the "old" way and should not be used, because of the high server load.

Comment: i was thinking to set interval on  $('.chatwindow').load('load.php'); for 500ms in this case i would get everything what in update , but do now know is this way are good or not , the 2 way you told its kind almost same and sounds better cuz hes run code only if there are new rows , but other way if u have like 100 users there will be always some new rows there

Comment: 500ms interval causes a high load on the browser and the server, i recommend taking a higher value as in the comment to the other answer. using longpolling the load adapts better to the actual number of users. With your approach, you have a constant high load on your server. If you have such a high load on your application consider using method 2 or 3 of my list.